# Remove parallax.js image when screen get's smaller

Tags: html, css, parallax.js

I'm using `parallax.js` to add parallax effect on my website. I would like to remove the `data-image-src` property when the screen size is smaller that 767pixels.

I know I should use `@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {...}` on my css file for that but I just can't figure out how to set the image property to none.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Panagiotis Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/circle.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parallax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>

    <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="sky.jpg">
      <div class="parallax-content">
          <h3 id="summary">Summary</h3>
          <hr>
          <div ng-include="'partials/summary.html'"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Some other parallax elements here -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Inside my index.js I added as ***linusg*** suggested the following jQuery code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function () {
    // Check window size
    if($(window).width() < 767) {
        // Unset data-image-src property
        $(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "");
    } else {
        // Set data-image-src property
        //$(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "sea.jpg");
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'a:not([target="_blank"])', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
});
```

Although the data-image-src value changes the image seems still to be there.

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does it work?

Comment: I added your code in my js file and it doesn't seem to work. I also added $(document).ready(function(){}); but still nothing. By the way I have no errors in the console.

Comment: Oh, you've misunderstood what I mean :D. I'll edit my post. Make sure you have included jQuery in your HTML.

Comment: I think you missunderstood what I meant :P. I added your code inside the $(document).ready... just as you edited on your answer. Still no change parallax image is still there. Also I included jquery as mentioned on my html (actually already had it).

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you get errors? Do you use the same code I posted? Can you post what you're using to something like http://pastebin.com? Are you sure you have jQuery included?

Comment: I tested in both mozilla and chrome. I have no errors in the console. I used exactly the code you posted ( will update the question soon ). And yes I'm sure i have jQuery include since I already use it for other purposes and it works just fine.

Comment: I just tested it again in Firefox using the builtin DOM inspector, and it just works. When I make the window smaller than 767 px, the `data-image-src` property is set to `""`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123630/discussion-between-panos-and-linusg).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jQuery`'s `$(window).width()` for this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    // Check window size
    if($(window).width() < 767) {
        // Unset data-image-src property
        $(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "");
    } else {
        // Set data-image-src property
        $(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "sea.jpg");
    }
});
```

Make sure to wrap your code into a `$(document).ready(...);` like below, see [this documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Full code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Other metadata and resources -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="sea.jpg">
            <div class="parallax-content">
                <h3 id="goals">Ambitions and Goals</h3>
                <hr>
                <div ng-include="'partials/goals.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    // Check window size
                    if($(window).width() < 767) {
                        // Unset data-image-src property
                        $(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "");
                    } else {
                        // Set data-image-src property
                        $(".parallax-window").attr("data-image-src", "sea.jpg");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!